# Auto Expand Coupon Field in WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, css, woocommerce

How to Auto Expand Coupon Field in WooCommerce on Checkout Page (so that it shows without having to click on it).

I tried this code which worked for a while but has now stopped:

```html
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'woocommerce_show_coupon', 99 );
function woocommerce_show_coupon() {
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(\'.checkout_coupon\').show();
});
</script>
';
}
```

Comment: If it was working previously i suggest to check updates for WooCommerce, your theme, or other plugins that could interfere with the jQuery selectors

Comment: I tried on blank installation etc and same error. I guess the code I made simply is outdated.